# mysql find records that contain words from a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql

SCENARIO:

I have one large table (let's call it "WordTable") with a list of words (let's call the field "theWord") that could have 10,000+ records.

I also have a large table (let's call it "MySentences") with a `VARCHAR` field (let's call the field "theSentence") that contains many varied sentences - it could have millions of records.

QUESTION:
What SQL could I write for the `MySQL database` to give me a list of which records in `MySentences.theSentence` contain any of the words from `WordTable.theWord` ?

Since there are many records in both tables, using numerous Like statements is not feasible.  Would FullText Search allow some capability here?

Hopefully this helps...  by the way, a "sentence" does not always need to have spaces... it could just be a collection of letters

Here are some MySQL scripts to illustrate the scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE `MySentences` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `theSentence` varchar(1000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `MySentences` (`id`, `theSentence`) VALUES
(1, 'hereisatestsentence'),
(2, 'asdfasdfadsf'),
(3, 'today is a blue sky'),
(4, 'jk2k2lkjskylkjdsf'),
(5, 'ddddddd'),
(6, 'nothing'),
(7, 'sometest');

CREATE TABLE `WordTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `theWord` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `WordTable` (`id`, `theWord`) VALUES
(1, 'test'),
(2, 'house'),
(3, 'blue'),
(4, 'sky');

ALTER TABLE `MySentences`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `WordTable`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `MySentences`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=8;

ALTER TABLE `WordTable`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
```

Comment: Could you provide the schema, some sample data and expected results? This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: good suggestion!  I've updated the question to include sample data and tables

Comment: What would the desired result look like

Comment: This looks like a pretty simple query. What do you expect if a sentence has two or more matching words? A single row or one row per match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a query using the [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) operator in the JOIN clause which will find any sentence that contains word. The LIKE operator uses wildcards `%` which will match anything.

```
SELECT
    A.theSentence, B.theWord
FROM
    MySentences A
    INNER JOIN WordTable B ON A.theSentence LIKE CONCAT('%',B.theWord,'%');
```

If you are interested in **just** the sentence that  was matched, you could use the `DISTINCT` operator to see distinct results:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT A.theSentence
FROM
    MySentences A
    INNER JOIN WordTable B ON A.theSentence LIKE CONCAT('%',B.theWord,'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You split your string into rows using something like this

[SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

You need a separator char probably space `_`, but also be carefull, may have to remove special chars  like  `, . : ;`

Then you join that result to your `WordTable` and find which words are there.